# codeigniter passing data from view to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to pass more than two value from view to controller using javascript based on dropdown value! here are my codes

```
<select name="class" id="class">
   <option selected value='-1'>--Select class--</option>
   <?php foreach($classes as $class){ 
      echo '<option value="'.$class['class_id'].'">'.$class['class_name'].'</option>'; }
      ?>
</select>
<select name="subject" id="subject">
   <option selected value='-1'>--Select Subject--</option>
   <?php 
      foreach($subjects as $subject) {                       
        echo '<option value="'.$subject['subject_id'].'">'.$subject['subject_name'].'</option>';
      }
      ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("change","#class",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var classid = $(this).val(); 
   $.post('<?php echo  site_url("system_ctrl/select_student"); ?>',{"class_id":classid},function(responce){
   $("#names").html(responce);
   });
</script>
```

i want to send value of id *subject* together with value of id *class* to the controller when value of class changes using javascript shown above.

Comment: you can pass N number of values like this {"class_id":classid,"subject":subject_id }

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any number of values like this,

```
$.post('<?php echo  site_url("system_ctrl/select_student"); ?>',{"class_id":classid, "subject":$('#subject').val()},function(responce){
    $("#names").html(responce);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on("change","#class",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
    var classid = $(this).val(); 
    $.post('',{"class_id":classid,"subject":$('#subject').val()},function(responce){
        $("#names").html(responce);
    });
$(document).on("change","#subject",function(e){ e.preventDefault();
    var subjectid= $(this).val(); 
    $.post('',{"subject_id":subjectid,"class":$('#class').val()},function(responce){
        $("#names").html(responce);
    });

Comment: may you arrange in a proper way please!

Comment: its not allowing me to arrange it. i dont know why. but your have to do  make that javascript for the both of the select field.

so that if you select subject directly. then it will work also and get the upper class data also